# Token mismatch between 'springboot' and React AXIOS CSRF communication

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, axios, csrf-token, x-xsrf-token

```
return  http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and()
                    //.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**").permitAll()    
                    //.and()
                    .build();
```

Spring Security

```
xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
```

axios default setting

I configured springboot as above and got the CSRF token from spring with GET and put it in the header to communicate with AXIOS, but the token is not correct.

How do I fix it?

The return should be OK, but I get a 403 forbidden error